# Retrieve "id" field values via VisualVM OQL query

Tags: visualvm, oql

Getting `obj.id` with an OQL query in Java VisualVM (1.8.0_45) returns JavaScript object id (a long value) instead of the value of the Java field. In other words JavaScript `id` field shadows the Java object `id` field. Java object value can be seen in the Instances browser, but how to retrieve it via VisualVM OQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to access Java object `id` field. This is a bug in OQL.
You can use the following workaround:

```
obj["wrapped-object"].getValueOfField("id")
```

Comment: In case you, like I, want to actually use this value in the where clause, you have to rewrap it. Assume this is a string value: `... where wrapJavaObject(obj["wrapped-object"].getValueOfField("id")).toString().equals("XXXX")`