# Formatting the result of oql in VisualVM

Tags: visualvm, heap-dump, oql

I have the following oql query running on visualvm against a heap dump and would like the `creationTime` field formatted as a date time field (its stored as `Long`).

```
select { id: s.id.toString(), createdAt: new Date(s.creationTime) }
from org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession s
```

The above query lists the following output (snipped)

```
{
 id = 1010827848,
 createdAt = sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeDate@66106135
}
...
```

So clearly its been "converted" into a Date but does not display it a human readable format. Doing a `toString()` on the date object just results in the field being displayed as `Invalid Date`.

1. Is it possible to format the the Long field as a Date field?
2. The id field's value also is off when queried using VisualVM. When I query the same heap dump using Eclipse Analyser I see the right value (which is `BE27C51E8BF185A2FB3AA9164EC0C647`). What could be happening to that?

Comment: "Invalid Date" seems to suggest the Date is not set to a proper value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The output shows that you are creating JavaScript Date object. The correct part of you OQL should be: `createdAt: new java.util.Date(s.creationTime)`
2. There is a known problem with a field, which is named `id`. See [Retrieve "id" field values via VisualVM OQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568374/retrieve-id-field-values-via-visualvm-oql-query) for more details. As a workaround you can use `s["wrapped-object"].getValueOfField("id")` instead of `s.id.toString()`

With above changes your query should be:

```
select { id: s["wrapped-object"].getValueOfField("id"),
createdAt: new java.util.Date(s.creationTime).toString() }
from org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession s
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer for the id field. The Date field turned out to be related to the version of Java I was using. Using Java 8 the field showed up fine irrespective of java.util.Date or the JavaScript Date! Only when using Java 7 the field did not return the Date value. Using java.util.Date with Java 7 resulted in a syntax error being returned.

Comment: Oh, you did not mention that you are still using JDK 7. JDK 7 uses Rhino to execute JavaScript, while JDK 8 uses Nashorn. `new java.util.Date(s.creationTime.longValue())` works for me on JDK 7.

Comment: `new Date(s.creationTime)` does not work for me on with VisualVM 1.4.1 on JDK 8u172. It returns `createdAt = Invalid Date`.